# show by induction that the sequence is monotonically increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

show by induction that the sequence :
[image]

is monotonically increasing ...
any help? it's a bit hard for me to write the induction hypothesis, I know that we must show that :

```
        $ a_1\le a_2$
        l
      Let it be for every natural n:
         $a_n\le a_{n+1}$ ----> hypothesis 
        and we must prove that it is also correct for $n+2$:
        $a_{n+1}\le a_{n+2}$
```

First what I said is correct? and I don't know how to continue from here... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need to use induction, we just need to show $a_n 
 < a_{n+1}$.

Let's start with
\begin{eqnarray*}
2  &<& 3 \\
4n+2 &<& 4n+3 \\
2(2n+1) &<& 2n+2 + 2n+1 
\end{eqnarray*}
divide by $2(n+1)(2n+1)$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{n+1}  < \frac{1}{2n+1} +  \frac{1}{2(n+1)}
\end{eqnarray*}
add $ \frac{1}{n+2} +\cdots + \frac{1}{2n}$ to both sides, so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{n+1} +\cdots + \frac{1}{2n} < \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots  + \frac{1}{2(n+1)}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Which means $a_n <a_{n+1}$.

Comment: but that is my hypnosis no ? and i must show that an+1<an+2 ..

Comment: Just run the argument backwards to show the hypothesis.

Comment: i still don't understand exactly what is the hypothesis and what i should show , can u edit it and type it again ? and show how u reached your final answer ?